# Add a Filter for datagridview based on multiple values of a datagridview column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter

I have a bound datagridview which contains a column “Graphicmacro”. In this column each row contains path for different files on my network drive. I have to add a filter that checks if the path of the file is correct( if the file exists), if it does the datagridview doesn’t change. If the path is incorrect, those rows should be filtered out(some rows have repeated paths as well).

I have been able to check for every row if the file exists and I am able to filter out all occurrences of the **first incorrect path** but it doesn’t filter out rest of the incorrect paths. I am new to vb.net and don't know how to do this for multiple incorrect paths. This is my code so far:

```
Public Function invalidpath()
Dim string2 As String
Dim string3 As String
Dim string4 As String
Dim dt As DataTable
dt = TblPartDataGridView.DataSource
Dim col As String = "graphicmacro"
For i = 0 To TblPartDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
   For Each row As DataGridViewRow In TblPartDataGridView.Rows
   Dim txt As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = row.Cells(graphicmacro.Name)
       If Not IsDBNull(txt.Value) Then
        string2 = Replace(txt.Value, "$(MD_MACROS)", "L:\EPLAN\Electric P8\Macros")
                If string2 <> "" Then
                    string3 = string2
                    If File.Exists(string3) Then
                        'Nothing
                    Else
                        string4 = Replace(string3, "L:\EPLAN\Electric P8\Macros ", "$(MD_MACROS)")
                        If InStr(string4, "'") Then
                            string4 = Replace(string4, "'", "''")
                        End If

                        string5 = col + " like '" & string4 & "'"

                        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string5
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return 0
End Function
```

Comment: You could manually add a bool column to the datatable and just set that to true or false depending on the result which you can choose to show or not show.  More than a few things and your filter text will get a bit gruesome.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thank you I will try to do that

Comment: @Plutonix I added a column(invalid) and updated the code:                                             
`If File.Exists(string3) Then
TblPartDataGridView.Item("invalid", i).Value = "T"
Else
TblPartDataGridView.Item("invalid", i).Value = "F"`
But it only changes the value of first row and doesn't update all the rows.

Comment: Please study [ask] and take the [tour].  Its hard to tell what might be wrong from an isolated snippet like that.  Edit your post to show the new code....I would not iterate the control, but the DataSource

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you so much for your help!! Your suggestion to iterate the datasource helped me fix it. The true and false values are being set properly in the datacolumn and using that column I am able to filter out the rows that I need.

Comment: StackOverflow can be a valuable resource for learning and problem solving.  But to use it successfully you need to have an idea how it works.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  New users get extra scrutiny to make sure the posts are good.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for the link I will go through it and make sure that in future I am clear about how to post. Thanks again for the help!